# Can a null value automatically occur in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, null, undefined, ecmascript-2016

In JS an "undefined" value could occur automatically by mistake.(eg:- if you call a function which does not return any thing)

Can a "null" value occur automatically?

Comment: Undefined does not occur because of a mistake, it is a designed feature. `null` cannot occur automatically (whatever automatically. means). You may be given `null` as a return value from an API, but it is neither automatic nor accidental.

Comment: Calling a function that doesn't exist throws a ReferenceError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` is what is returned when you attempt to access a property that is not there or an array value that is not there.  It is also the initial value of a variable that has been declared, but not assigned a value yet.  These are not really mistakes, but the way the language is designed when you request a value that is not there.

`null` does not occur by default like `undefined` does.  If a variable or property or return value is `null`, that is because some programmer or API specifically assigned or returned `null`.

Also, calling a function that does not exist throws a `ReferenceError`.